# Video.js not showing controls in Firefox when adding video dynamically

Tags: video.js

I am trying to offer a playlist of videos and only play a video once its link was clicked. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>WW Video Player</title>
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.0/video.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<video id="video_player" class="video-js vjs-default/skin" width="800" height="600" data-setup='{ "controls": true }'></video>

<script type="text/javascript">
    videojs("video_player", {}, function() {});

    function SelectVideo(path)
    {
        var mplayer = videojs("video_player", { "controls": true, "autoplay": false });
        mplayer.src({ type:"video/mp4", src: path});
        mplayer.play();
        mplayer.requestFullScreen();
    }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="SelectVideo('/path/file.mp4'); return false;">Play Video</a>

</body>
</html>
```

In the `<video>` tag, I have tried adding plain `controls` and removing `data-setup`, but I can't get the controls to show up.

Furthermore, `mplayer.requestFullScreen();` isn't working, either - here's Firebug's error message:

```
TypeError: mplayer.requestFullScreen is not a function
```

I'm running Firefox 22.0 on Windows 7 64bit.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Video.js is good and bad at the same time.  I appreciate the work that's gone into it, but   I've spent days getting it to work correctly.  I wish I'd found your answer earlier, codoplayer looks good.

Videojs goes wrong whenever a javascript error occurs, and subsequently fails to set the correct classes on the control bar etc.

The bad javascript could be in your own code, and there is one in video.js that affects Firefox.

First, make sure your own scripts aren't failing...

The function that *must* be changed in video.js is: vjs.Player.prototype.techGet()

When an exception occurs, it handles it, then re-throws at the end.  Replace the line 'throw e;' with 'return null;'

Why?  There are methods within video.js that do not seem to realise that techGet could throw..  here is an example:

```
vjs.Player.prototype.currentSrc = function(){
  return this.techGet('currentSrc') || this.cache_.src || '';
};
```

It throws an exception on techGet whenever the tech is flash, which is common in Firefox, IE8 etc.  It will *never* reach **this.cache_.src || ''**.  It looks like that wasn't the intention, so it's probably a bug.

If interested in IE8, you will have to do something with all the calls to innerHTML, they may fail and will need replacing with a method that works on the DOM instead.